# iPhone: How to reenable MKUserLocation 'blue dot'?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

Enabling the 'blue dot' which shows current location in my application by

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES
```

Disabling/hiding the dot by

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = NO
```

in order to drop a pin. So far so good.

Adding an annotation pin at 'userLocation' and dragging it around in the map to a new location. After that I want to show the blue dot again by setting showsUserLocation to YES again - but it simply does not show up! What could be the problem? Is there a way to force it to show again (reset userLocation?) with any other method? Which events are involved?

Grateful for any help on this one..

Answer (score 3):

check if you are customizing your annotationView with `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`
 method try:

```
if (annotation==_mapView.userLocation ) {
    return nil;
}
else {
    //...
    //costumizing pins for other annotations on mapview

    //return customized annotationview
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why the above code worked for me. But Will Johnson's code does the trick.

Comment: Its not working when I turn off and then turn on the location service.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])  return nil;
```

Using the class rather than annotation==_mapView.userLocation means that is you stop using _mapView.userLocation or whatever, this line does not break.